# Java JDBC Derby Syntax Error

Tags: java, sql

Hi I have a problem with my syntax in my java code. I have a `tableview` which gets its data from a SQL database. I have created 3 tables in the database `book`, `customer`, `order`. When I click a button I want to take the selected books and add them to the `order` table.
Here is the code from the main program (calling the method from db):

```
if(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().iterator().hasNext()) { 
                    db.insertOrder(new Bestellung(customerid,table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().iterator().next()));
```

The table `book` is fixed. Just the two other tables `customer`,`order` are dynamic.

The problem:

I create the values in the `order` table like this

```
String ct = "CREATE TABLE Order (" + "Order_Id integer generated always as identity, " + "CUSTOMER_ID BIGINT" + "ISBN, CHAR(13) " + "PRIMARY KEY(Order_Id))";
```

and so on...

I insert into `order` table like this. (Here is the syntax problem in the `String i` That's the position where the compiler says it doesn't work..)

```
    String i = "INSERT INTO ORDER(CUSTOMER_ID,ISBN), VALUES(?,?)";
    Connection conn = null; 
    PreparedStatement stmt = null; 
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString);
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(i);
        conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE); 
        stmt.setLong(1, order.getCustomerId());
        stmt.setString(2, order.getBuch().getISBN());
        stmt.executeUpdate();  
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {

        try {
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and here is the syntax error which I got

> Syntax error: Encountered "ORDER" at line 1, column 13.

So how do I have to correct my syntax in the `string i`? Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: can you create a table with the name of Order??

Comment: Oh the name 'Order' was also not possible. Seems like this word is reserved in SQL

Comment: i have changed it. now it works thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO ORDER(CUSTOMER_ID,ISBN), VALUES(?,?)
                                   ^
```

The comma is superfluous.  Also, in your `CREATE TABLE`

```
... + "ISBN, CHAR(13) " + ...
           ^
```

This comma is also extraneous.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use reserved words/keywords as Table name, you should:

1. MySQL: use '  , like : `select * from 'Order'`
2. Oracle, PostgreSQL: use " , like : `select * from "Order"`

**But** it is bad practice, try to change your table name.

You have another Error that answered by @Jim Garrison.